# Cannot to resolved to a type

Tags: java

I'm newbie in Java. I have two class:

```
abstract class Money {
    protected int amount;

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        Money money = (Money) object;
        return amount == money.amount
                && getClass().equals(money.getClass());
    }

    static Money dollar(int amount) {
        return new Dollar(amount);
    }

    abstract Money times(int multiplier);
}
```

And:

```
public class Dollar extends Money {
    Dollar(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    Money times(int multiplier) {
        return new Dollar(amount * multiplier);
    }
}
```

I would like use these as:

```
@Test
public void testMultiplication() {
    Money five = new Money.dollar(5);
}
```

But in this method I have error:

> Money.dollar cannot be resolved to a type.

This is example from book about TDD. What should I do? How can I fix this error?

Comment: `Money.dollar(int)` is a method, not a constructor. You don't use `new` for calling methods. Call it with `Money.dollar(5)`, not `new Money.dollar(5)`.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood. Please add a new answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example you're instructing Java to create a variable of type Money which will hold the reference to a Money object that you try to create with one of the abstract Money class' static methods after assigning a piece of memory to it with the *new* keyword. As you can see; instead of a constructor you're trying to call a static method of an abstract class.

Shortly you have two problems there:

1- Trying to create an object without a constructor.

2- Trying to instantiate an object from an abstract class which is impossible in Java.

When you try the following (this is called *`Dynamic Method Binding`*) you'll see it's going to work:

```
    @Test
    public void testMultiplication() {
        Money five = new Dollar(5);
        //rest of the test case logic
    }
```

or

```
    @Test
    public void testMultiplication() {
        Money five = Money.dollar(5);
        //rest of the test case logic
    }
```

In conclusion; please read about object creation and inheritance basics in Java.

Happy hacking.

Comment: Best answer. According to me.

Answer (score 2):

`Money.dollar(int)` is a method, not a constructor. You don't use `new` for calling methods.

Call it with `Money.dollar(5)`, not `new Money.dollar(5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Money five = new Money.dollar(5);
```

to

```
Money five = Money.dollar(5);
```